# redirect user if not authenticated

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have a Blazor WASM App with a page (/upload) that is only accessible by authenticated users. The Page is marked with `@attribute [Authorize]`

When I launch this page directly and no user is logged in everything works as expected (redirect to root).

But when I use the menu to navigate to the page *after* the user was logged out in *another* browser tab the page is loaded and my code in `OnInitializedAsync()` is executed which throws an exception because no user is logged in. The navigation is done via a `<NavLink ... >` Tag

Why isnt the user redirected to root and how can I globally set that the user should be redirected to root (and NOT per page)?

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked already, but don't worry fam -- I got you! Update your `App.razor` page to handle the Authorized checks:

```html
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity != null && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <Loader />
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h2>Looks like you're lost, we didn't find anything at this location.</h2>
                        <p>Try navigating to the Dashboard or going back in the browser.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```